# Weblogic application deployment using wlst script gives out of memory exception

Tags: java, memory, deployment, weblogic, wlst

I am deploying an application using wlst script in Weblogic 12.1.2 and JDK 1.7.0.75. 
All  the tasks(create domain, cofigure Admin Server, Start Server, connect) written in wlst script works, except for application deployment. App Deployment script:

```
deploy(appName='App1', path='D://Applications//App1', targets='AdminServer', stageMode='nostage', securityModel='DDOnly')
```

Through console the application is deployed without any memory issues. In console, I have chosen: Target style as "Install this deployment as an application", Security Model as "DD Only: Use only roles and policies that are defined in the deployment descriptors.", Staging Mode/Source Accessibility as "I will make the deployment accessible from the following location" and Plan Staging Mode/Plan Source Accessibility "Use the same accessibility as the application".

Do I have to set any specific memory settings in wlst script for it to deploy successfully?
Out of Memory Exception:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource
>   [beans-config.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:
>   PermGen space

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about wlst script. But when i happen to see such errors while working with WebLogic, I change the permgen values in the following file:

> Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\mydomain\bin\setDomainEnv.cmd

(if you are working on UNIX system, see the setDomainEnv.sh file). Look for attributes

```
MEM_MAX_PERM_SIZE_64BIT=-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
MEM_MAX_PERM_SIZE_32BIT=-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

Based on your Operating System (32 bit or 64 bit), set these values to higher digits. Restart your WebLogic instance.

Comment: I am using windows OS and could deploy successfully using weblogic Admin console. So, the memory settings in SetDomainEnv.bat might be fine. I would like to know whether I could set any memory attributes in wlst script before deploying to avoid the out of memory exception.

Comment: The application that you are trying to deploy would be requiring more permsize and hence might be the issue. However, I was trying to find information on Oracle website and i found the following page https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs90/config_scripting/config_WLS.html#1003498 which i felt could give a hint to you. This page specifies only how to monitor the JVM parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The application was deployed successfully after starting the server by specifing memory arguments as described below:
startServer('AdminServer','my_domain','t3://localhost:7001','weblogic','password','user_projects/domain/my_domain','true',60000,'false',**jvmArgs='-XX:MaxPermSize=256m, -Xms512m, -Xmx512m'**)

Answer (score 0):

As you are deploying a app into domain level, best way is using Administration Console -> deployments -> install and then, change your deploy configure on the UI. Most situation, it will go through.

WSLT be used to deploy app to partition is good reference.

Java 8 have much better memory management. Update your JDK version to 8, this problem may go away.